# Calling async method synchronously using Task.Run ends up in a deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I thought calling async method using Task.Run does not cause any deadlocks. But it does:

```
async Task<string> GetIdAsync()
{
    return Task.Run( () => IncInt64Async( "id", 1L ) ).Result.ToString(); // Deadlock
}

async Task<Int64> IncInt64Async( string key, Int64 inc );
```

I know I should use await. So this one works:

```
async Task<string> GetIdAsync()
{
    return await IncInt64Async( "id", 1L ); // of course, no deadlock.
}
```

But I'm just trying to understand WHY the first attempt is causing a deadlock. In my understanding of async, deadlock only happens when an async method captures a synchronization context and try to return to the context while the context cannot let it.

Moreover, GetIdAsync() is called inside a Task.Run() so it's running with no sync context anyway:

```
Task.Run( () => {
    some code...
    id = getIdAsync();
    some code... 
}
);
```

So I went crazy and tried all the variations I could think of but still all attempts causes deadlocks:

```
Task.Run( () => IncInt64Async( "id", 1L ).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult() ).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
IncInt64Async( "id", 1L ).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
Task.Run( () => IncInt64Async( "id", 1L ) ).Result;
Task.Run( () => IncInt64Async( "id", 1L ) ).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
Task.Run( async () => await IncInt64Async( "id", inc ) ).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
Task.Run( () => { var task = IncInt64Async( "id", inc ); task.Wait(); return task.Result; } ).Result;
```

BTW, Inside the implementation of IncInt64Async, it uses several await with no ConfigureAwait(false).

What could possibly be the reason?

---

The implementation of IncInt64Async():

```
async Task<Int64> IncInt64Async( string key, Int64 value )
{
    Task task = null;
    byte error = 1;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    lock ( c.WriteLock )
    {
        c.Write( key, value );

        _readTask = task = _readTask.ContinueWith( async o =>
        {
            if ( ( error = await c.ReadByteAsync() ) == 0 ) // **BLOCKS HERE**
            {
                bytes = new byte[ 8 ];
                await c.ReadAsync( bytes, 0, 8 );
            }
            NumWaits--;
        } ).Unwrap();
    }

    if ( task != null )
        await task.AnyContext();

    if ( error != 0 )
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    return BitConverter.ToInt64( bytes, 0 );
}
```

'c' is an instance of TcpHandler.

It basically writes over tcp, and reads from tcp.

I'm using ContinueWith() to align reads.
I've tried passing TaskScheduler.Default to ContinueWith().

Comment: From where do you call that? UI application, asp.net application, console?

Comment: @Evk it's from an console application. Even GetIdAsync() is called inside Task.Run like this: Task.Run( () => id = GetIdAsync(); ... )

Comment: If it's console application, how it actually deadlocks? Deadlock with async usually happens in applications with some notion of "UI" or "request" thread, not in console applications.

Comment: @Evk Exactly. It's against my understanding. It just can't pass IncInt64Async().Result although it works if I use await IncInt64Async().

Comment: Maybe the code of IncInt64Async will help. Or even better - full example (minimal example which we could run to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Could you create a full, minimal, reproducible example? Essentially, something people can copy + paste and immediately reproduce?

Comment: @wooohoh, Calling `.Result` or `.Wait` in an async method causes deadlocks. Don’t mix blocking and async code. read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Not only source for `IncInt64Async` would be useful here, but also the exact line which blocks in this method could help us help you

Comment: I have tried all your options on Linqpad and there's nothing which gets blocked, please review and make changes, which can cause the deadlock.
Even from Main method, I am using `Task.Run`

Comment: So, your original question is incorrect, its a different method leading to Deadlock and rightly so, it is full of potential landmines.Shared object, Lock, also can you read twice on same handler, `c.ReadByteAsync()` & `c.ReadAsync`, also why not use `await` in place of `ContinueWith`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Yes. But I still don't understand why await does not lock while .Result locks despite all thread offloading. c.ReadAsync() only happens if c.ReadByteAsync() results in 0. I actually tried to use await instead of ContinueWith, but IncInt64Async() should be able to handle multi-thread calls, so I needed to align all reads and simple await couldn't handle that. I needed another lock mechanism to handle it so I went a simpler route.